# Pass to line the text automatically

Tags: longtable

I have an array **longtabu** in which each cell has an array **tabular**. The two columns have the same size and the table is centered horizontally.
I would like to know how to make the text pass to line automatically.
And I would also like to know how to make increase the table in width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|X|}
\hline    
    \begin{tabular}{l} something \\ \\ \lipsum[3-56] \end{tabular}  
& 
    \begin{tabular}{l} something \\ \\ \lipsum[3-56] \end{tabular} \\
\hline    
\end{longtabu}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would avoid `tabu` if possible. Instead you could use a `tabularx` (or `xltabular` if you need page breaks in between rows)
- it looks as if one could avoid your complicate construct of nested tables by adding line breaks. This will also allow automatic line breaks if you have columns of fixed with, e.g. `p` or `X`
- the table already spans the whole available text width. If you want to make it even wider, you will have to increase the text width, e.g. with the `geometry` package

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
something\bigskip\linebreak\lipsum[3-4]
&
something\bigskip\linebreak\lipsum[3-4]\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank for your help, i get a error: _LaTeX Error: File `xltabular.sty' not found._, i use _overleaf.com_. With this exemple i don't have any error: https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/examples/a-longtable-plus-tabularx-example/rcrxtjbrvyft

Comment: @problème0123 works fine in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/dhmqvwgtrswr

Comment: Hello, humm ok, with your link i don't have any trouble. Thank for your help.